# MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED error occurs sometimes at RTF email sending via Outlook Redemption SafeMailItem

Tags: outlook, outlook-redemption

Similar Delphi code (multiple emails with RTF body sending via Outlook-Redemption) below has been working well without any problems for years. 
Recently when our company changed to Outlook365 (Office365) we had to buy the newest Redemption (version 5.21) since the code stopped working: MAPI_E_CALL_FAILED. This issue is solved by the new version.
However foreign colleagues keep reporting me MAPI_E_OBJECT_CHANGED error by around every 5th or 6th emails. They use Exchange server 2010. We use Exchange 2013 and have no problem.
I do not know if it is related the version of Exchange server.? or RTF body? What else could be the reason?

[Error message pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDVqW.png)

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  ovSafeMailItem, ovOutlookSession : OleVariant;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ovSafeMailItem := CreateOLEObject('Redemption.SafeMailItem');
  ovOutlookSession := CreateOLEObject('Redemption.RDOSession');

  if FileExists('defaultBody.rtf') then
    reBody.Lines.loadfromfile('defaultBody.rtf');
end;

function GetRTF(reBody: TJvRichedit): string;
var strStream: TStringStream;
begin
  strStream := TStringStream.Create('') ;
  try
    reBody.PlainText := False;
    reBody.Lines.SaveToStream(strStream) ;
    Result := strStream.DataString;
  finally
    strStream.Free;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendEmail;
var ovItem : OleVariant;
begin
  ovOutlookSession.Logon;
  try
    try
      ovItem:=ovOutlookSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Add('IPM.Note');
      ovSafeMailItem.Item:=ovItem;
      ovSafeMailItem.Recipients.Add(edtAddr1.text);
      ovSafeMailItem.Recipients.Add(edtAddr2.text);
      ovSafeMailItem.Recipients.ResolveAll;
      ovSafeMailItem.Subject:=edtSubject.Text;
      ovSafeMailItem.RTFBody:=GetRTF(reBody);
      ovSafeMailItem.Send;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Cannot send email!'+#13+#13+'Error message: '#13+E.message,mtError,[mbOK],0);
      end;
    end
  finally
    ovOutlookSession.Logoff;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.SendEmail2;
var ovItem : OleVariant;
begin
  ovOutlookSession.Logon;
  try
    try
      ovItem:=ovOutlookSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items.Add('IPM.Note');
      ovItem.Recipients.Add(edtAddr1.text);
      ovItem.Recipients.Add(edtAddr2.text);
      ovItem.Recipients.ResolveAll;
      ovItem.Subject:=edtSubject.Text;
      ovItem.RTFBody:=GetRTF(reBody);
      ovItem.Send;
    except
      on E: Exception do
      begin
        MessageDlg('Cannot send email!'+#13+#13+'Error message: '#13+E.message,mtError,[mbOK],0);
      end;
    end
  finally
    ovOutlookSession.Logoff;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.btnSendClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SendEmail2;
end;
```

Comment: Which line of your code throws the error? Also, there is absolutely no reason to use SafeMailItem with the RDOMail object.

Comment: I do not know yet since I could not reproduce the error on my laptop. I will try to find out. Dmitry, do you mean using SafeMailItem is an unneccessarry risk?

Comment: Yes, since oItem in your code is an RDOMail object, which never raises any prompts.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, I changed the code, not using SafeMailItem anymore. ovItem.Send line throws the error. Any idea?

Comment: What is your latest code?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, The latest code is like SendEmail2 method.

Comment: Is it the same error? Send a message to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.